# Find the recursive formula for $I_m:=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}^m},\enspace \,m\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, solution-verification, recursion

Find the recursive formula for:

$$I_m:=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}^m}\,\,,\,\,\,\,m\in\mathbb{N}$$

---

**My attempt:**

$$I_m=\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}^m}=\left[\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}^m}\right]+m\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+1}^m(x^2+1)}dx$$

$$=\left[\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}^m}\right]+m\int \left(1-\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}^m} dx $$

$$=\left[\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}^m}\right]+m\left(\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}^m}dx- \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}^m(x^2+1)} dx \right)$$

$$=\left[\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}^m}\right]+m\left(\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}^m}dx- \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}^{m+2}} dx \right)$$

$$=\left[\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}^m}\right]+mI_m-mI_{m+2}$$

$$\Longleftrightarrow mI_{m+2}=\left[\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}^m}\right]+(m-1)I_m$$

So we finally get:

$$ I_{m+2}=\frac{1}{m}\left[\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}^m}\right]+\frac{m-1}{m}I_m$$

---

Is this correct? Would be great if someone could look over it :) Thank you a lot as always

Comment: Yes. Tried $I_1, I_3, I_5$ and $I_2, I_4, I_6$ thru integral-calculator.net. The integration by part also looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

$$\dfrac{d\dfrac x{(x^2+1)^{n/2}}}{dx}=\dfrac1{(x^2+1)^{n/2}}-\dfrac{nx}{2(x^2+1)^{n/2+1}}\cdot2x$$

$$=\dfrac1{(x^2+1)^{n/2}}-n\cdot\dfrac{1+x^2-1}{(x^2+1)^{n/2+1}}$$

Integrate both sides w.r.t $x,$

$$\implies nI_{n+2}-(n-1)I_n=\dfrac x{(x^2+1)^{n/2}}+K$$